# How Bad is it to change the root element dynamically in react

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I work with bunch of junior dev's they are new to react. i have some experience but not an expert. They are using react router but for changing screens they are directly changing the root element. The application has the worst folder structure and looks horrible. I just want to some explanation that how bad will this affect the performance if the same application is released for production.

I am trying to implement best practices but I still need time and we are in a crunch to deliver in a few days.

The Root Element Initially

```
ReactDOM.render(<Login/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

When Edit Button Is Clicked

```
function handleEditButton(row){
  ReactDOM.render(<EditShelf shelf={row}/>, document.getElementById("root"));
}
```

Just want to understand how bad is this practice and whats will be the major impact when this application is launched for production

Comment: If the page is totally different, I'd say this is fine.  One thing I would say it would be a good idea to call `unmountComponentAtNode`, -> https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#unmountcomponentatnode

Comment: But how would any external libraries work along with approach ? Like redux material-ui which needs a wrapper around the root component. And I don’t think react reconciler works with this approach.

Comment: Why would it be a problem?, if another lib is written correctly, it should be handling comonentDidMount / Unmount etc,..  If you have a component that can't handle been mounted / unmounted, the problem is with the component.

Comment: `ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <React.Fragment>
            <Client />
            <App />
          </React.Fragment>
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );` how would I do this if I replace the root element constantly ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it probably won't affect performance very much, though it's an horrible practice.

It shouldn't be so awful performance-wise because that way the reconicler has to replace the entire host tree without even try to traverse and compare every node.

Comment: so, it is fine for now, but has to be refactored to use react-router for navigation would that be a right approach ?

Comment: Yes, you should definitely use a single entry point component for your application and then a router like react-router.